# javascript composition to have chaining functionality to cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to set up testing with cypress and want to chain with my custom helper function.

```
 const Utils = (props) => {
     const state = { cy: props.cy || { get: () => {} }, }
     const getByTestId = ((cy, dataTestId) => cy.get([data-test-id=${dataTestId}])).bind(null, state.cy) 
     return { getByTestId, } 
}
```

and I have test wrapper like this

```
const AutoCompleteWrapper = (cy) => {
    const utils = Utils({ cy }) const { getByTestId } = utils

    const autoCompleteContainerElem = () => getByTestId('autoComplete')
    const autoCompleteInputElem = () => autoCompleteContainerElem().find('input')
    const selectResults = () => getByTestId('autoCompleteResult')
    return { autoCompleteInputElem, selectResults, }
 }
```

With above setup. In order to get nested data-test-id element, I need to use wrap the parent with getByTestId again.

Is there any suggestion to make custom function to be chainable?

Ex) getByTestId('autoComplete').getByTestId('childTestId')

Comment: I'm curious, what are you trying to solve here? It seems way more complex than needed. Cypress gives the option to add custom commands to `support/commands.js`. What you can do there is for example something that looks like this:
```js
Cypress.Commands.add('autoCompleteInput', function(element) {
  cy.get(`[data-test-id=${element}]`)
    .find('input')
})
```

But since I don't know what you are trying to do I can't help you with the next step in the actual testfile. It would look like this:
```js
cy.autoCompleteInput('autoComplete')
// action you want to do
```

Comment: @Mr.J. I guess I did not research enough. I did not know about command. That seem to solve some of my problem.